# Publishing verification result back to pact Broker

Tags: pact

Does anyone have an example of how to publish verification result back to  the pact broker ?
I'm using maven implementation for all phases (Generate/Publish and verify)
The only page I found is this one: https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact_broker/wiki/Provider-verification-results

but it is not clear to me how to implement it by maven provider plugin

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the documentation you are looking for.

https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm/tree/master/pact-jvm-provider-maven#publishing-verification-results-to-a-pact-broker-version-354

Be aware that there is currently no configuration option to turn off the publishing of verifications when running verifications from your local machine (Ron will be adding it soon) so you need to ensure that your CI always runs after your local tests!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Beth

I had to add the following section into my plugin setup in order to publish the results back:

```
       <pactBroker>
          <url></url>
          <authentication>
            <username></username>
            <password></password>
          </authentication>
        </pactBroker>
```

This is how my plugin looks like:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>au.com.dius</groupId>
  <artifactId>pact-jvm-provider-maven_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>3.5.5</version>
  <configuration>
    <pactBrokerUrl></pactBrokerUrl>
    <pactBrokerUsername></pactBrokerUsername>
    <pactBrokerPassword></pactBrokerPassword>
    <projectVersion>1.0.0</projectVersion>
    <serviceProviders>
      <serviceProvider>
         <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <host>${K8S_APP_URL}</host>
        <port>${K8S_NODE_PORT}</port>
        <path>/</path>
        <pactFileDirectory>target/pacts</pactFileDirectory>
        <pactBroker>
          <url></url>
          <authentication>
            <username></username>
            <password></password>
          </authentication>
        </pactBroker>
     </serviceProvider>
    </serviceProviders>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```